# How to get json data for each OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, json

I am developing an Android app which fetches Data from website as `Json`,it has 100 `ListView` data.I want to fetch each ticker values for each `OnClickListener`. My code is given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=INR&limit=100";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new GetContacts().execute();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String id1 = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewCoinActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",id1);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}



/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node


                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String symbol = c.getString("symbol");
                    String price_inr = c.getString("price_inr");
                    String percent_change_24h = c.getString("percent_change_24h");
                   String market_cap_inr = c.getString("market_cap_inr");
                    String rank = c.getString("rank");
                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                  /*  JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String office = phone.getString("office"); */

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("symbol", symbol);
                    contact.put("price_inr", price_inr);
                    contact.put("percent_change_24h", percent_change_24h);
                    contact.put("market_cap_inr", market_cap_inr);
                    contact.put("rank", rank);
                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
             Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get Data from Server",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name","symbol",
                "price_inr","percent_change_24h","market_cap_inr","rank"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.symbol,R.id.price_inr,R.id.percent_change_24h,R.id.market_cap_inr,R.id.rank});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

for each onclick i want to fetch data from following based on the ticker
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/

Comment: What is the error that you are getting or what is the problem regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but maybe I did not understood your question.
But for you to get the value on onItemClickListener, you simply use your contact list on your item position.The same list of your Adapter. Like this

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String id1 = contactList.get(position).getIdMethod();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ViewCoinActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id",id1);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```